# how to add search filter with multiple array in ios

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeFjA.png)

In this condition how to add search filter on this view controller.
I was add search display controller on it. but it is working only for one array.
kindly help me 
Thanks

Comment: How have you set things up? We need to see some code before being able to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR artistName CONTAINS[cd] %@", keyword, keyword];
self.musicEntities = [self.musicEntities filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].mutableCopy;
```